# mAudioDataから値を取り出したい

Tags: xcode, swift4

■環境
Mac/High Sierra 10.13.6/swift4.2/xcode 10.0

mAudioDataから音声データを取り出したいのですが、
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/audioqueuebuffer/1502113-maudiodata
を参照してもよくわかりませんでした。

試しに

```
let opaquePtr = OpaquePointer(inBuffer.pointee.mAudioData)
let mAudioDataPrt = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(opaquePtr)
for i in 0..<numPackets{
    print(mAudioDataPrt[Int(i)])
}
```

としたところ値は取り出せたのですが、値が正しいのかが全くわかりませんでした。
mAudioDataは下記のコールバック関数で取得しており、
AudioServiceクラス内部のprepareForRecordメソッドで基本的に準備をし
そのあとで

```
let err: OSStatus = AudioQueueStart(audioQueueObject!, nil)
```

を呼んで録音をスタートしていました。
memcpyでバッファにコピーすればよいというのも理解はしているのですが、
今やりたいことはmAudioDataを配列として取り出したいことです。
動的にバッファの先頭の何バイトかを削除しつつ末尾に付け加えることをしたいのですが、
何分にもバッファだと扱いづらいため、配列で扱うことを考えています。

==========================コールバック関数============================

```
func AQAudioQueueInputCallback2(inUserData: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?,
                           inAQ: AudioQueueRef,
                           inBuffer: AudioQueueBufferRef,
                           inStartTime: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
                           inNumberPacketDescriptions: UInt32,
                           inPacketDescs: UnsafePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>?) {
    let audioService = unsafeBitCast(inUserData!, to:AudioService.self)
    audioService.writePackets(inBuffer: inBuffer)
    AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAQ, inBuffer, 0, nil);
}
```

=====================以下AudioServiceのメソッド======================

```
func prepareForRecord() {
    print("prepareForRecord")
    var audioFormat = self.audioFormat

    AudioQueueNewInput(&audioFormat,
                       AQAudioQueueInputCallback,
                       unsafeBitCast(self, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self),
                       CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
                       CFRunLoopMode.commonModes.rawValue,
                       0,
                       &audioQueueObject)

    startingPacketCount = 0;
    var buffers = Array<AudioQueueBufferRef?>(repeating: nil, count: 3)
    let bufferByteSize: UInt32 = numPacketsToWrite * audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket

    for bufferIndex in 0 ..< buffers.count {
        AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(audioQueueObject!, bufferByteSize, &buffers[bufferIndex])
        AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(audioQueueObject!, buffers[bufferIndex]!, 0, nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: mAudioDataの型はAudioStreamBasicDescriptionのmBitsPerChannelに寄ってくると思っています。ここが16だとInt16でしょうかUInt16でしょうか。

Comment: 録音データなので入力バッファなのでしょうが、「この領域を処理しなさい」と手続きを呼び出している最中にバッファの内容を変更している様に読めてしまうのですが、そんなことして大丈夫ですか？もう一つバッファを用意して、続きのデーターは使用中でないバッファに追加していき、手続きが終わったら、すかさす「つぎはこっちの領域を処理してね」と、2つのバッファを交互に使うほうが間違いが無いような気がするのですが

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。確かにおっしゃる通りです。２つのバッファを使用しようと思います。